# Syntax to reference a resources variable in an Azure DevOps condition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Devops YAML pipeline with several stages. Some should run when resources.pipeline.myPipeline.sourceBranch starts with 'refs/heads/release/'. Which of the 500 different syntaxes that are used for pipeline expressions am I supposed to use?

- `condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(resources.pipeline.myPipeline.sourceBranch, 'refs/heads/release/'))`
- `condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith($(resources.pipeline.myPipeline.sourceBranch), 'refs/heads/release/'))`
- `condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['resources.pipeline.myPipeline.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/'))`

or something else?

Comment: The third of these did work, using `variables['resources.pipeline.myPipeline.sourceBranch']`.